# What is best practice for shipping editable XML with your application?

Tags: android

Hi fellow android developers!
I am developing an application where I have XML files that contain my data. When doing edits in these data, I save the data to the XML files, thus these must be editable.
This I would be able to achieve using the local storage for my application with the `openFileOutput` method of my Context.
But how would I go around shipping my program with these datafiles already there, with some pre-filled data?

I can see the option of shipping with some XML files in my res/xml or res/raw, duplicate them to the local data storage, but then I would be unable to remove the files in my resources, and this would take up too much storage.

Please tell me what you would do in this case?

Comment: Is downloading them an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not include editable files with your application.

So you will have to write them to the local file system some way. Either by downloading them or including them as raw resources via openRawResource().

Comment: Any chance of this being changed at some point and would anyone guess what the reason for this is?

Comment: It's just the way it is. Presumably, all data files were considered 'resources' in much the same way as embedded resources in Windows EXE/DLL, and not intended to be changed. Hopefully this will change, as shipping pre-populated SQLite databases would be very useful. I'd recommend against using XML, as it is slow to parse on resource constrained devices.

Comment: @phil If it is recommend to not use XML, as it is slow to parse on resource constrained devices, how is it that Android uses it to inflate UI components?

Comment: One of the reasons behind not shipping editable files, is that you will always be able to restore that app back to a fresh state without having to redownload.

Also, regarding UI layouts, Android turns the xml format into some binary format, which helps with loading and parsing.

Comment: @creen The UI XML that ends up in the installed APK isn't XML text, it's a compiled version of the XML, which is significantly faster to process. This transformation happens at build time, using aapt.

Comment: Thanks guys! This makes sence.
Both the possibility of clearing the application to its default state and the compilation of XML files.